Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN.elements accessible
I want to set a default value when the http response json return null. if the type is string, set default value is "", if the type was list, set the default vaue []. this aciton will make the client side easy to check the response. This is the java code how I do it:
package com.guannet.you.admin.rest.aop;

import com.guannet.frame.web.core.RestResult;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;


@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<RestResult<?>> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, @NotNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getParameterType() == RestResult.class;
    }

    @Override
    public RestResult<?> beforeBodyWrite(RestResult<?> body, @NotNull MethodParameter returnType, @NotNull MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (Objects.isNull(body)) {
            return null;
        }
        Object data = body.getData();
        if (Objects.nonNull(data)) {
            setDefault(data);
            return body;
        }
        var field = ReflectionUtils.findField(body.getClass(), "data");
        if (Objects.nonNull(field)) {
            data = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(field.getType());
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(data)) {
            setDefault(data);
        }
        return body;
    }

    private void setDefault(Object obj) {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(obj.getClass(), field -> {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            Object val = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, obj);
            if (val != null) {
                return;
            }
            Object defaultValue = null;
            if (field.getType() == String.class) {
                defaultValue = "";
            } else if (field.getType() == List.class) {
                defaultValue = Collections.emptyList();
            } else if (field.getType() == Map.class) {
                defaultValue = Collections.emptyMap();
            }
            ReflectionUtils.setField(field, obj, defaultValue);
        });
    }
}

but when I run this code in JDK 21, shows error like this:
2024-10-15 09:59:24:210 [t-1] [http-nio-6100-exec-4] ERROR c.g.y.admin.support.AdminGlobalExceptionHandler - service error
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN.elements accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @7a362b6b
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:315)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:804)
    at com.guangdanet.youxue.admin.rest.aop.ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.lambda$setDefault$0(ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.java:52)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:707)
    at com.guangdanet.youxue.admin.rest.aop.ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.setDefault(ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.java:51)
    at com.guangdanet.youxue.admin.rest.aop.ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.beforeBodyWrite(ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.java:37)
    at com.guangdanet.youxue.admin.rest.aop.ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.beforeBodyWrite(ResponseBodyDefaultValueAdvice.java:23)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.processBody(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.beforeBodyWrite(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)

it look like the response list is immutable and did not allow to change. what should I do to set the default value for the response? This is the RestResult look like:
public class RestResult<Content> {
    private int code = HttpStatus.OK.value();
    private boolean success;
    private String message = "";
    private Content data;
}

the response content is json.

Reasonably simple , your Object[] array is "final" . You can never change that! You cannot reinstantiate an element.

Considering, if you have instantiated a String first and then referred to it as an Object, look up the API docs for String and use a method to change the internal class value so you are not altering the final Object[] array instantiations!

The error message is quite clear. (At least to me.) module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module JDK 21 is modular but your code is not - hence the unnamed module indicates your code. Maybe consider making your code modular.

@Abra exactly! nothing more to say (+1 for asking a good question)

The java.base module is not open and does not open the java.util package, so you do not have reflective access to private fields of classes in that package.
JLS 7.7:

For code outside a normal module, the reflective access granted to types in the module's exported (and not opened) packages is specifically to the public and protected types in those packages, and the public and protected members of those types.

You can open the java.util package yourself using the --add-opens option
java --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

However, I think this is a dangerous path that will make your code harder to maintain. In my opinion, to replace null with an empty string for String fields and an empty collection for Collection fields when serializing your objects, you should either use your own null field serializers, @JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = NullStringSerializer.class), or create DTO objects with the values ​​you need and serialize them.
